# c# file downloading problem

Tags: c#, .net, download

I am using this code to download file from server and parse data from JSON notation:

```
        WebClient wcl = new WebClient();
        Uri url = new Uri(tickurl);
        string srlz = wcl.DownloadString(url);
        var dict = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(srlz);
```

When I use it with http://deepbit.net/api/ + my token (URI returns JSON data) it works well.

But with https://mtgox.com/code/data/ticker.php it stucks on 3rd line of the function(data downloading).

What am i doing wrong? Both URLs return same JSON formatted data.

[add] it's not issue with https, this code works well enough with other https services. i am wondering if this could be a problem with SSL cert.

**SOLVED: turned off SSL certificate validation. thanks**

Comment: Have you tried looking in Wireshark to see what traffic is involved?

Comment: maybe because it is a https url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it's failing due to a security problem. When I fetch with `wget`, I get:

> ERROR: certificate common name `www.mtgox.com' doesn't match requested host name`mtgox.com'

It's fine when I fetch with `wget` using the `--no-check-certificate` flag.

I don't know whether you can persuade `WebClient` not to check certificates... but a better option would obviously be to get the certificate fixed.

Alternatively, try this URL instead: `https://www.mtgox.com/code/data/ticker.php` - note the `www` at the front. That fetches in `wget` without any issues.

Comment: thanks! i turned off SSL cert check and it works :) though this is potentially insecure

Comment: @Steel: Did you try using the second URL instead?

Comment: tried just now, doesn't work as well. solution upper seems to be the fittest, will look deeper later

Answer (score 1):

The Url: https://mtgox.com/code/data/ticker.php doesn't even open up in browser. It starts downloading the 'ticker.php' file. Your server is misconfigured. The code is fine. Most probably the server is not properly configured to process .php files as scripts.

Comment: thanks, but it's not my server, and Chrome seems to open it well.

Comment: maybe it is configured right, but just serves the request as a download. dont know how WebClient handles them

Comment: Yeah that's a possibility too.

Answer (score 1):

it is a certificate error like Jon Skeet said.

Have a look here to find a easy solution

[WebClient + HTTPS Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536352/webclient-https-issues)

you shouldn't use this for all request, only for debugging