# Android Xamarin C#: Https with ServiceStack and self signed certificates

Tags: c#, android, ssl, xamarin, servicestack

So I am changing all my Http webservices to Https using a self signed certificate for testing (for an android app I am making) and it is all working perfectly server side, I know this because I can add the certificate to my PC's certificate store and access the site perfectly, how ever I am having trouble on the client side when it comes to my android app making calls to it.

my Servicestack calls look like this:

```
        var client = new JsonServiceClient(stubServicesBaseUrl);

        return client.Get(new GetLastStatusUpdate()).StatusUpdates.Last();
```

and these used to work when it was only http but since I added code to add the self signed certificate to the android trusted credentials store the calls have stopped working and instead it seems that the request times out.

```
        byte[] certificate;
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(Assets.Open("ScoutTestCert.crt")))
        {
            using (var byteStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                streamReader.BaseStream.CopyTo(byteStream);
                certificate = byteStream.ToArray();
            }
        }

        var installCertificate = KeyChain.CreateInstallIntent();
        installCertificate.PutExtra(KeyChain.ExtraCertificate, certificate);
        StartActivity(installCertificate);
```

The above code adds the certificate to the android trusted store in the "user" section and allows me to navigate to the site through the internet app on the androidEmulator without problem, so it seems the problem only appears when trying to make ServiceStack calls in my apps code.

Am I missing something in my code, like extra set up that service stack needs or something like that? I have been struggling with this problem for a few days now and at a real road block!
I am trying to keep the webservice calls as servicestack as I want it to be PCL rather than android specific code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ServiceStack's [.NET Service Clients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-client) uses .NET's BCL's built-in `HttpWebRequest` in order to have the self-signed certificates work with .NET HTTP Clients you need to register a [custom Certificate Validation Callback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16616904/85785), e.g. the callback below would enable all certificates to succeed:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += 
    (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

But you would want to limit the validation down to work with your self-signed certificate.

An alternative to using ServiceStack's HttpWebRequest based Service Client is to use the [PCL HttpClient-based JsonHttpClient](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-client#jsonhttpclient) instead which has the benefit where it can be configured to use [ModernHttpClient](https://github.com/paulcbetts/ModernHttpClient) with:

```
JsonHttpClient.GlobalHttpMessageHandlerFactory = () => 
    new NativeMessageHandler()
```

Which instead of using the .NET HTTP Client stack uses the native HTTP libraries available on the underlying iOS and Android platforms. This should then let you use any certificates registered with Android.

In order to use untrusted self-signed certificates registered in .NET with ModernHttpClient you would need to use the [pro version of ModernHttpClient](http://log.paulbetts.org/modernhttpclient-pro-edition/) as [mentioned on this thread](https://github.com/paulcbetts/ModernHttpClient/issues/43).

Comment: So I tried adding in the ServerCertificateValidationCallback line as the first thing that happens in my app so that any certificate should be accepted (just to test this works for me) and I still appear to get the same "WebException: request timed out" error message. I do not understand why this exception is occuring, I read it is because the request is being sent and nothing is recieved back, is this correct?
I think my next course of action maybe trying another xamarin android built in https service and seeing if that hopefully works.

Comment: @wootank Not sure but I'd look at first at getting a basic .NET [HttpWebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) to work using a url directly, i.e: `(HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("url")` which will remove any additional layer above .NET's BCL classes. If it doesn't work I'd submit a bug report to Xamarin so they can tell you what the underlying issue is.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help, In the end we decided to go alone with your second suggestion with the JsonHttpClient and ModernHttpClient and it all works swimmingly :)