# Copying data from URL through VB.net

Tags: vb.net

This is the code I am using to copy some data from a URL to text file:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://01hw860645vm7/piwebapi/streams/P0RCrLRNEwjUSpQKLB67jLng60cAAAMDFIVzg2MDY0NVZNN1xBR0lfQ1VSUkVOVA/value")
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = CType(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        Dim datastream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(datastream)
        Dim strdata As String = reader.ReadToEnd
        Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
        file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("C:\Users\1212832\Desktop\Test.txt", True)
        file.WriteLine(strdata)
        file.Close()
        TextBox1.Text = strdata
    End Sub
End Class
```

And I am getting the following error: "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."
I have even written this script in app.config:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true"/>
    </system.net>
```

But still no result. Please help.

Comment: Well I'm not very good with VB so sorry!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebClient + HTTPS Issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536352/webclient-https-issues)

Comment: it's nothing to do with the proxy. It's an SSL certificate issue, seems like the certificate on the server is missing or doesn't match the URL you're using. Try making the URL using a FQDN (e.g. `https://01hw860645vm7.example.com/...`)

Comment: M sorry but I did not know what FQDN is. Moreover, I've tried doing (https://01hw860645vm7.example.com/...) but it did not help. Any kind of suggestions from your side would be thankful..

Comment: FQDN means "Fully Qualified Domain Name"  -see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name. using example.com won't work because I made it up (the clue's in the name, it's an example!). Use the domain that the computer you're accessing is part of. e.g. if it was a Google computer you might use 01hw860645vm7.google.com , or if it was a microsoft computer you might use 01hw860645vm7.microsoft.com .

Comment: "https://01hw860645vm7/piwebapi/streams/P0RCrLRNEwjUSpQKLB67jLng60cAAAMDFIVzg2MDY0NVZNN1xBR0lfQ1VSUkVOVA/value"

Comment: I am totally new to this so please dont mind. "https://01hw860645vm7/piwebapi/streams/P0RCrLRNEwjUSpQKLB67jLng60cAAAMDFIVzg2MDY0NVZNN1xBR0lfQ1VSUkVOVA/value" This is the url I want to access and mine is a microsoft system. So what am I suppose to do now ?

Comment: @tanmayrajoria Is your computer in the domain (active directory) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_domain ? If so you have to know in what domain your computer is. Without that information nobody can help you.

Comment: @tanmayrajoria think of it like a person's name. A man's first name could be David. But without knowing the surname, you will confuse him with lots of other Davids. Same with the machine. 01hw860645vm7 is probably just the first part of its name, and it's likely the SSL certificate is matched with its full name, not just the first name. The only reason you can even attempt to access it just using the first name is because you're on the same network (and probably domain) as it - a bit like if you call a member of your family by their first name you know who it is, but not so with a stranger

Comment: so if you find out what domain your computer is on and it'll be the same for that machine. From your command prompt run `ipconfig /all` and one of the outputs should be "Primary Domain Name" - use that value in your URL.

Comment: Hi there. Thank you for the explanation. I've found the domain and used it in my url as "https://01hw860645vm7.(domain)/piwebapi/......

Comment: But I did not get any result

Comment: @tanmayrajoria "I did not get any result". Do you mean you get the same error again? or you get an empty response or something? Please clarify.